# The constructor BorderStroke(Color, BorderStrokeStyle, null, null) is undefined

Tags: java

I am trying to give my Hbox a Border but in my project, it gives an error back. Don´t understand because in my friend's project it works perfectly.

```
`HBox hbox= new HBox();
hbox.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.GREEN, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, null, null))); 
hbox.setSpacing(50); 
hbox.setPadding(new Insets(20)); 
hbox.getChildren().add(imv); 
hbox.getChildren().add(label);`
```

Comment: It seems to work fine, try saving and refreshing the project. Select the project directory in the package explorer, right click, and select refresh. If that doesn't work try restarting eclipse

Comment: I already did but it doesn´t change anything. Still an error.  :/

Comment: Please indent you're code with four spaces to make it easier to visualize, or put back sticks in front and behind the code. Here's how you do it:

    `HBox hbox= new HBox(); 
    hbox.setBorder(new Border(new 
    BorderStroke(Color.GREEN, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, null, null))); 
    hbox.setSpacing(50); hbox.setPadding(new Insets(20)); 
    hbox.getChildren().add(imv); hbox.getChildren().add(label);`

Answer (score 3):

I found that if you `import` the wrong `Color` you will get the same error back:

```
//WRONG IMPORTS
import java.awt.Color;
//OR
import com.sun.prism.paint.Color;
```

> The constructor BorderStroke(Color, BorderStrokeStyle, null, null) is undefined

This is easy to mess up because Eclipse will automatically recommend any of the 3 `Color` imports as options.

Remove the incorrect `import` for `Color` that you currently have, and instead make sure you manually import all the correct Classes at the top of your current Class so you do not use the wrong one:

```
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStroke;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStrokeStyle;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
```

Notice this is now `javafx.scene.paint.Color` instead.